# Exponential limit of the form $0^\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I was trying to derive a general expression for the limit $$\large{y=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}}$$ where $\lim_{ x \to a} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{ x \to a} g(x)=\infty$
$$$$
I managed to reach till here: $$\ln (y)=\lim_{x\to a} g(x).\ln(f(x))$$

The result I'm supposed to reach is $$\LARGE{y=e^{\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}}$$
$$$$
I would be grateful for any help. Many thanks!

PS. This was given to me by a friend. I'm not really sure if the question is correct.

Comment: Do you mean of the form "$1^{\infty}$"? Because the form "$0^{\infty}$" would obviously converge to $0$.

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ is also the undefined form $\frac{0}{\infty}$. So perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @barakmanos Initially I too had thought of that. But my friend categorically referred to $0^\infty$

Comment: How exactly does your friend fit into all this???

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I thought of that. Is the question given incorrect?

Comment: @barakmanos Sir, initially he had given this to me as a question. He said that the closed form he mentioned was the 'answer'.

Comment: Have you considered the case of $f(X)=x^(1/x)$?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x \to a} \exp \left ( g(x) \ln(f(x)) \right )$; this is the standard trick. But in this form you will get $\exp$ of something going to $-\infty$ which is again zero.

Comment: @A.Riesen Sorry sir, I couldn't really understand. How am I to consider the case? Regardless of the value of $a$, shouldn't $$\lim_{x\to a} x(1/x)=1?$$

Comment: @Ian Thanks Sir. This would mean that the given closed form is incorrect, right?

Comment: If you use the supposed result for that function you would get the limit of one but in fact the actual limit is zero@user342209

Comment: @A.Riesen Sir, how can the limit be 0? $$\lim_{x \to a}x (1/x)=\lim_{x \to a} 1=1$$

Comment: @user34 it is not possible to reach $y=e^{\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. To see it let's consider a counterexample.

Let $$f(x)=x, g(x)=\frac1x\Rightarrow\\l_1=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}(x)^{\frac1x}=0$$

But $$l_2=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}x^2}=e^0=1\neq0$$